# Which version of C++ can I use in smart contracts?

Tags: smart-contract, dapp, development, c++

Which version of C++ can I use to implement smart contracts?

For example: C++11, C++14 or C++17? Do we have any constant or doc where it is defined?

Also, in my understanding the code is sandboxed, where can I find the restrictions?

Is the version defined in
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/4f293115f34112e843885befc4a69fce1e137aa2/CMakeLists.txt#L17 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer: Currently *EOS* smart contracts are written in C++17. For more details see the official SDK, [CDT](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt) (Contract Development Toolkit) which is based on clang 7.

Answer (score 11):

`eosiocpp` currently compiles contracts using c++14. [cib](https://tbfleming.github.io/cib/eos.html) compiles contracts using the c++17 language, but c++14 library.

sandboxing: contracts are compiled to WASM. Normal OS functions (filesystem, threading, etc.) are not available.

Note: cib requires an up-to-date Firefox (fastest) or Chrome (slow loading).

Comment: Is the version defined in
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/4f293115f34112e843885befc4a69fce1e137aa2/CMakeLists.txt#L17 ?