# Which IDE can I use for EOS C++ source code?

Tags: c++

What I need is an IDE as advanced as Eclipse, that would tell me if certain imports are missing, variables not declared, compile errors, and so on...  I am using Linux so Visual Studio won't work for me (unless a Linux version).

The question about C++ version is already answered here:
[Which version of C++ can I use in smart contracts?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/143/which-version-of-c-can-i-use-in-smart-contracts)

I need an IDE that would allow me to import eos-master project and allow me to code the smart-contracts inside the contracts directory, with all the coding warnings/solutions that advanced IDEs usually give.

Answer (score 6):

Today I'm using Visual Code (which works in Linux, because I'm on OSX) but I think the easiest one to setup with a nice intellisense (autocomplete), debug and tests is CLion from Jetbrains.

In this workshop Kevin Heifner teaches how to setup the IDE: https://objectcomputing.com/resources/events/webinars/building-apps-with-eos/recording

Comment: right, I also use clion, vs code is also a good choose, but you must to learn many plugins and do many configurations.

Answer (score 1):

## Eclipse

Using Eclipse works just fine for me.

In order to get it to see all of the appropriate header files, you have to make a symbolic link to the correct folder.

For example, if I want to use the hello contract from my home directory:

```
~/hello/hello.cpp
```

I would do the following:

```
cd ~/hello
ln -s /path/to/eos
ln -s /path/to/boost
```

Then in Eclipse I would choose to create a new project using existing makefile, and give it the `~/hello` directory as the location.

The intellisense will then automatically read the eos and boost folders and it makes things much easier!

Here is an additional tutorial for using Eclipse (including how to do the symbolic links on Windows):
https://steemkr.com/eos/@tokenika/using-eclipse-ide-for-eos-smart-contracts

## Visual Studio

I found a tutorial that lets Windows 10 users use Visual Studio:
https://steemit.com/eos/@mmcs/building-eos-with-visual-studio-2017-for-windows-10

Comment: Any plugins to you would recommend ?

Comment: Well I usually work in command line terminal for everything. So if you like using vim then you can get vwrapper, which lets you use vim commands in Eclipse. Other than that though, I don't actually use any plugins

Comment: Vim is great, please don't get me wrong, but it is a skill many of us are not willing to pursue :)  Thank you for a reply !

Answer (score 1):

You can use **EOS Studio**.  Supports **Mac**, **Windows**, and **Linux**

https://www.eosstudio.io/

- Highlight and autocomplete for EOSIO specific syntax
- Templates of system contracts: eosio.token, eosio.msig, etc
- One click to build smart contracts
- Deploy to local, Kylin/Jungle testnet, or EOSIO mainnet
- Show build errors inline

---

They have tutorials as well:

https://medium.com/@ObsidianLabs/eos-studio-tutorial-1-set-up-the-environment-for-eosio-development-53fe3f9cb1f